# Use an IOS xcode project on another mac

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, import, project

I have an xCode project that I want to move on a new mac with a USB key.
How can I import the project in the new mac's xCode?
do I need to create a nex project and copy all files from the first one inside? 
Or does it exist a way to import an existing project into xCode to continue its development?

Comment: Just open the project file on the other mac? You might need to export the developers certificates en profiles to the new machine.

Comment: You can run project without any changes, but get the project in another MAC machine(by USB as you mentioned) and run it.
But yes as @rckoenes said, you need to install development certificates into new machine if not install previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`You don't do anything. Just Put your USB & Try to run the Project.`

**Let me know if you have any problem.**